# Type guard but for "extends"

Tags: typescript

How can I check if a type "extends" another type?

Let's say I have:

```js
interface Edible { }

interface Fruit extends Edible {
    isFruity: boolean
}
interface Veggie extends Edible {
    isHealthy: boolean;
}

interface AlsoNice {
    nice: boolean;
}
interface AlsoCool {
    cool: boolean
}
// and so on so forth...
```

And some type guards:

```js
function isFruit(thing: Edible): thing is Fruit {
    return 'isFruity' in thing;
}
// etc...
```

In the following function, if I want to return something that unions with `AlsoNice` if it extends `Fruit`, otherwise it unions with `AlsoCool`. But if I use the `is` type guard, it will raise an error on both of the returns.

Code:

```js
function yum<T extends Fruit | Veggie>(thing: T): T extends Fruit ? T & AlsoNice : T & AlsoCool {
    if (isFruit(thing)) {
        return { ...thing, nice: true };
    } else {
        return { ...thing, cool: true }
    }
}
```

Error: `Type 'T & { nice: true; isFruity: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'T extends Fruit ? T & AlsoNice : T & AlsoCool'.`

I might be wrong, but I think this is because the type guard makes TS treat `thing` specifically as `Fruit` instead of `T extends Fruit`, so what I need is to modify the type guard to return `thing extends Fruit`. However I'll get an error `'thing' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

How can I satisfy the conditional type in the function signature that uses `extends`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using a conditional type as the return type will always result in the need for type casts inside the function body. This is just a limitation of the inference TypeScript is capable of and you can read a little about that in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735).

But the good news is that most use cases for a conditional type return can be covered just by using an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). In this case, the following seems to have the desired effect:

```
function yum(thing: Fruit): Fruit & AlsoNice;
function yum(thing: Veggie): Veggie & AlsoCool;
function yum(thing: Edible) {
    if (isFruit(thing)) {
        return { ...thing, nice: true };
    } else {
        return { ...thing, cool: true }
    }
}
```

When using that, you can call the function and the return type will be inferred in the following ways:

```
const nice_fruit = yum({isFruity: true}); // nice_fruit: Fruit & AlsoNice
const cool_veggie = yum({isHealthy: true}); // cool_veggie: Veggie & AlsoCool;
const wierd_thing = yum({notfruit: true, notveggie: true}); // Produces a type error: No overload matches this call.
```

---

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBNgCMA2KDeyAvgFAmiSyIoBiUArsGMhAB6QjoDOamuBJZEOTAudRmACeALmRYA9vLxwQJUhWjwkyAGoQA5vuAo2Hbr2x5k%20QcNEAJCHBxgAFjLmLlIANxqyGlTaAII4XPIAcsDaNsLIINEQsgpKTr7%20gVoooeEAwl7WtkIIXsleaf4kMPQgCGDA8iAiYgxMABRuoPqyGJYQAJSynSD6zcjiTIVxUBBg9FBNAOSiE1KLIk3D%20n6kVTV1DU2S9AC2Ha5dsquD463MAGTIOZGJftW19Y3Ix2dbsnqGYw3AFGFCPZ75JRvfafI6nc6XCz8fpTOwwZBtFZ3BEjfoo2JxYQzOYLazIAB0lK2ABp4okhgwUEQ-HEiCwwgJCUTZvMmoRKeSacgSkoGfQmUViJUSiAuMwEkgAPowO7IAC833h%20CxEg8YEZRH6PmQAHoTXSlSqJFdVeCwi8kCQZXLhV5FQA3Ayg9Was7ariOZxuPUGo2m80inAer3Gf4xsFPe2QnB%20Z3MADuxig6EVWx9Pza%20BA8jAVqYYogtOLYE9gKSyH14sNxrNyAAClB5Oh6EgeHAG5IAA4mKCdqCyCLyZDyT1QHDyODoZAnOBgBCuCA8To8BDOHDkkhAA)